# Axioms for mutual information

Tags: it.information-theory, pr.probability

I am interesting in axiomatic justifications for concepts in information theory. I have found many axiomatizations for [Shannon's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) and for the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback-Leibler_divergence), as well as their variations (for some examples, see [this survey](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/10/3/261) or these books: [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=9Xsj7AWmV8UC&dq=aczel+information+book+entropy&source=gbs_navlinks_s), [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=OPg_L04nem4C&dq=aczel%2520information%2520book%2520entropy&source=gbs_similarbooks)). However, I have not found any results directly for the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

Are there any results that show that some intuitive properties uniquely characterize the mutual information of a joint distribution of two random variables?

Comment: Can I rephrase this as : Given a random sequencegenerated by a random variable X and another by a random variable Y, is their an algorithm to find the mutual information of X and Y.

You want an axiomatic justification of info theory argument?

Comment: I think I have in mind something different. All I'm saying is: look at the mutual information as a function from pairs of random variables to real numbers. I'm looking for a theorem of the form: a function (with this domain and codomain) satisfies properties 1 to n if and only if it's the mutual information of the two random variables.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've seen such a characterization before, but since mutual information is a KL divergence, it might be possible to add axioms to those for the KL divergence...

Answer (score 3):

My paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12647.pdf provides an answer to this question. In particular, here is a quote from the introduction:

Our main result is Theorem~6.6, where we prove that the mutual information $\mathbb{I}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ of an ordered pair of random variables is the unique function (up to an arbitrary multiplicative factor) on pairs of random variables satisfying the following axioms:
[image]